# How to return $http.post() object with factory function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, error-handling, angular-factory

When I tried to return a $http.post() object from a factory function with Angular, it throws me this error:

[image]

Below is my code:

AngularUtils.js

```
Fenrir.factory('AngularUtils', function ($http, $log, $window) {

var AngularUtils = {
    save: function(url, obj, errors, not_show_error_toast) {            
        not_show_error_toast = typeof not_show_error_toast !== 'undefined' ? not_show_error_toast : false;
        loaderShow();
        if (angular.isDefined(obj.id)) {
            return $http.put(url + obj.id + '/', obj).
                then(function onSuccess(response) {
                    loaderHide();
                    angular.extend(obj, response);
                    errors = {};
                }), function onError(response) {
                    loaderHide();
                    handleErrors(response, status, errors, not_show_error_toast);
                };
        } else {
            return this.create(url, obj, errors, not_show_error_toast);
        }
    },
    create: function(url, obj, errors, not_show_error_toast) {            
        not_show_error_toast = typeof not_show_error_toast !== 'undefined' ? not_show_error_toast : false;
        return $http.post(url, obj).
            then(function onSuccess(response) {
                loaderHide();
                angular.extend(obj, response);
                errors = {};
            }), function onError(response) {
                loaderHide();
                handleErrors(response, status, errors, not_show_error_toast);
            };
    },
}

   return AngularUtils
})
```

Admin.js

```
var Fenrir = angular.module('Fenrir', []);

Fenrir.controller('AdminController', function ($scope, $http, AngularUtils) {
    $scope.createScreen = function () {
        AngularUtils.save('/admin/saveScreen', $scope.record, '', '').then(function (hubs) {
            $scope.hubs = hubs;
            console.log('In ctrl ' + $scope.hubs);
        });
    }
})
```

How do I return the $http.post() object properly?

Comment: Please show how you injected into admin.js, so show the controller constructor.

Comment: Does `this.create(url, obj, errors, not_show_error_toast)` return a promise?

Comment: Can you also post the implementation of handleErrors, you haven't adequately _separated the concerns_,  instead  you've put async UI affecting code inside the factory method that doesn't have access the the UI $scope. When you move into a factory implementation you can't normally just take your controller code and paste it into the factory definition, you have to remove any dependencies to the UI, the fact that you pass through an `errors` object is a key indicator or _red flag_ that the call is not right, errors should come from the promise handling, we don't pass them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking closely at the error message:

```
TypeError: AngularUtils.save(...).then is not a function
```

This is saying that there is no function named `then()` that is returned from `AngularUtils.save(...)`. Which indicates that the `save()` function did execute, but it did not return a *promise* as expected.

So your factory method did execute, but because you did not return a promise we can only speculate as to which of the pathways the execution finally resulted in.

### Update: syntax error in original script

In trying to justify my solution for you, I found that your `$put().then()` response handler had a syntax issue, there was a bracket in the wrong place, the `onError` function is supposed to be the second argument to the `then` function, not after it. Your code should look like this:

```
return $http.put(url + obj.id + '/', obj).
            then(function onSuccess(response) {
                loaderHide();
                angular.extend(obj, response);
                errors = {};
            }, function onError(response) {
                loaderHide();
                handleErrors(response, status, errors, not_show_error_toast);
            });
```

Subtle, but important, if you do not have strict compilation on, then the factory function was simply not compiled correctly, which could cause your error.

---

In factory methods where *one* or *some* pathways will return async promise deferrals (futures) then the default pattern, although verbose, is to return a single deferral wrapped around the whole method execution, then for each of the response pathways you can choose to resolve or reject the response through the original promise that was returned from the function.

*there are different libraries and techniques to do this, [see **AngularJs and Promises with the $http Service** by Rick Strahl](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Oct/24/AngularJs-and-Promises-with-the-http-Service#The-Verbose-Way) for a walkthrough of the common implementations.*

```
save: function(url, obj, errors, not_show_error_toast) {            
    var defer = $.Deferred();

    not_show_error_toast = typeof not_show_error_toast !== 'undefined' ? not_show_error_toast : false;

    if (angular.isDefined(obj.id)) {
        loaderShow(); // NOTE: let create manage the loader start if it needs to
        $http.put(url + obj.id + '/', obj).
            then(function onSuccess(response) {
                loaderHide();
                // HACK: because .then is used instead of .success, you probably want the response.data, please review this
                angular.extend(obj, response.data);

                defer.resolve(obj);
            }, function onError(response) {
                loaderHide();
                handleErrors(response, status, errors, not_show_error_toast);

                defer.reject(response);
            });
    } else {
        // If create is a deferral, it should be safe to return it directly
        return this.create(url, obj, errors, not_show_error_toast);
    }

    return defer.promise();
},
```

> **Note:** Only call a *start* or *show* utility or state operation in the same scope that also calls the reciprocal *end*/*hide*/*stop*/*close*. The code can work if you do not follow this rule but it gets harder to maintain as your project evolves, for that reason I've moved the `loaderShow();` call into the branch that we *know* will always call `loaderHide()`. This functional *scope* can not make the assumption that the `create()` function will eventually call `loaderHide()` for us.
>
> > This is a common, but bad habbit we all need to grow out of ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works! Great explanation and tips